# How to remove first few letter and print the last title in php

Tags: php, wordpress, substr

I have got the permalink and the page title. I need to remove the only permalink and print the title in using PHP.
Here is code: 
`$string = "http://example.com/blog/PageTitle"`

From here remove the `http://example.com/blog/` and print only `PageTitle`

I tried it:

```
$string = 'http://example.com/blog/PageTitle';
$remove_text = 'http://example.com/blog/'
$count = strlen($remove_text)
echo substr($string, $count);
```

N.B: my `$string` and `pageTitle` are changable like `http://example.com/about/PageTitle`, `http://example.com/contact/PageTitle2` etc.

Comment: the word `PageTitle` is also changable, right?

Comment: thanks @jaypeerachai it works properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$string = strrev($string);
$str_arr = explode ("/", $string);
$pageTitle = $str_arr[0];
$pageTitle = strrev($pageTitle);
echo $pageTitle;
```

This should work.

Comment: Welcome @Sabbir